# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Everything"

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, cocoapods

I am getting this error when I am trying to run my React Native app in iOS:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Auth":
  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Auth

    RNFBAuth (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth`) was resolved to 10.5.1, which depends on
      Firebase/Auth (~> 7.4.0)

CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Crash was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      Firebase/Core (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
        Firebase/CoreOnly (= 5.0.0)

    RNFBApp (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app`) was resolved to 10.5.0, which depends on
      Firebase/CoreOnly (~> 7.4.0)

    RNFBDatabase (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/database`) was resolved to 10.5.1, which depends on
      Firebase/Database (~> 7.4.0) was resolved to 7.4.0, which depends on
        Firebase/CoreOnly (= 7.4.0)

CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Database":
  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Database

    RNFBDatabase (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/database`) was resolved to 10.5.1, which depends on
      Firebase/Database (~> 7.4.0)

CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Firestore":
  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Firestore

    RNFBFirestore (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/firestore`) was resolved to 10.5.1, which depends on
      Firebase/Firestore (~> 7.4.0)

CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Messaging":
  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Messaging

    RNFBMessaging (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging`) was resolved to 10.5.1, which depends on
      Firebase/Messaging (~> 7.4.0)

CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Storage":
  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Storage

    RNFBStorage (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/storage`) was resolved to 10.5.1, which depends on
      Firebase/Storage (~> 7.4.0)

CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseCore":
  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Crash was resolved to 3.9.0, which depends on
      Firebase/Core (= 3.9.0) was resolved to 3.9.0, which depends on
        FirebaseCore (= 3.4.4)

    RNFBDatabase (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/database`) was resolved to 10.5.1, which depends on
      Firebase/Database (~> 7.4.0) was resolved to 7.4.0, which depends on
        Firebase/CoreOnly (= 7.4.0) was resolved to 7.4.0, which depends on
          FirebaseCore (= 7.4.0)

    RNFBDatabase (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/database`) was resolved to 10.5.1, which depends on
      Firebase/Database (~> 7.4.0) was resolved to 7.4.0, which depends on
        FirebaseDatabase (~> 7.4.0) was resolved to 7.4.0, which depends on
          FirebaseCore (~> 7.0)

CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseInstanceID":
  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Crash was resolved to 3.2.0, which depends on
      FirebaseCrash (= 1.0.4) was resolved to 1.0.4, which depends on
        FirebaseInstanceID (~> 1.0)

    RNFBMessaging (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging`) was resolved to 10.5.1, which depends on
      Firebase/Messaging (~> 7.4.0) was resolved to 7.4.0, which depends on
        FirebaseMessaging (~> 7.4.0) was resolved to 7.4.0, which depends on
          FirebaseInstanceID (~> 7.0)
```

My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "prueba3000",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "eslint": "eslint **/*.tsx **/*.ts",
    "build-testing": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease",
    "build-android": "cd android && ./gradlew bundleRelease",
    "clean": "cd android && ./gradlew clean",
    "postinstall": "npx jetify"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.2.3",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.9.0",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.0.8",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/hooks": "^2.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/image-editor": "^2.3.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.7",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^3.0.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^10.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^10.5.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/database": "^10.5.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^10.5.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^10.5.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^10.5.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.6",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^3.0.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "json2formdata": "^1.0.4",
    "lottie-ios": "^3.1.3",
    "lottie-react-native": "^3.3.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "object-to-formdata": "^4.1.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "^0.63.4",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.31.0",
    "react-native-countdown-component": "^2.7.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "^7.3.1",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.16.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.3",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^9.1.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.0.0-alpha.9.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.0.3",
    "react-native-video": "^5.1.0-alpha8",
    "react-native-video-controls": "^2.6.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "sprintf-js": "^1.1.2",
    "tipsi-stripe": "^7.5.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.7",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@svgr/cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.16",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.63.37",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.9.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.9.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.15.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
    "faker": "^5.1.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-transform-stub": "^2.0.0",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.6",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

In my Podfile, I have this: `platform :ios, '10.1'` And I have tried also with 10.0 and 9.0.

I have run:
`pod install`
`npx pod install`
`pod install --repo-update` and `pod update Firebase/core`.

When running `pod update Firebase/core` I got this error: `` [!] No `Podfile.lock' found in the project directory, run `pod install'. ``. But I can't do pod install.

If anyone could give a gint of how solve this, I would really appreciate that. Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

run command from the project root folder.

if **npm**

> `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json`

if **yarn**

> `rm -rf node_modules yarn.lock`

remove **^** from every package

set package version from the concerned library if that version exists then ok, otherwise set version that actually exists

run command

> `npm install` or `yarn install`

then

> `cd ios`

run command from ios folder

> `rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock`

then

> `pod install`

Comment: Thanks!! I followed all the steps and now I can do the pod install. Apparently I have some build issues now, but I think I can handle them by myself. Have a nice day!

Comment: In my case, I need to update my repo as well with "pod repo update" or "pod install --repo-update"

Comment: its start working now thanks

Comment: For me, what worked is removing version of Firebase service in Podfile, then following these steps except I didnt do the whole:

remove ^ from every package

set package version from the concerned library if that version exists then ok, otherwise set version that actually exists

Answer (score 19):

I had a similar issue with with the error `CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Database" ....`

Running `pod repo update` and then `pod install` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I having same issue when installing pod, see below error.

[image]

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Stripe":
In Podfile:
Stripe (~> 23.8.0)

I fixed and working,

- required a higher minimum deployment target.
- Xcode -> General -> Minimun Deployments Target
- Select iOS target higher e.g 13.0.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the reference to `Firebase/Crash`.

It was deprecated a few years ago in favor of `Firebase/Crashlytics`

Comment: Thanks! That helped. I still have some problems aynway, but I think I can handle them mysellf. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

In my case removing *Podfile.lock* helped. But this operation is quite unsafe.

Comment: In what way is it unsafe? Please elaborate.

Comment: @TashPemhiwa `Podfile.lock` freezes all the versions of dependencies including pods without explicitly specified versions. There is no guarantee that `pod install` provides exactly the same pod versions and you could successfully compile your project.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but none of the above worked for me. What worked was adding the following to the plugins section inside app.json:

```
       [
        "expo-build-properties",
         {
          "ios": {
             "useFrameworks": "static"
           }
         }
       ]
```

Hopefully this helps someone!

Answer (score -1):

if you use NotificationExtension in pod file note the version is used in here after commented try to run pod install then uncomment and run pod install once more

Comment: # target 'NotificationExtension' do
#   pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 18.3.0' # eg 6.31.0
# end