# Is react-navigation compatible with react-native-macos?

Tags: react-native, macos, react-navigation

I've created a fresh new React Native MacOS app and added in react-navigation. I am using React-Native 0.64 as the MacOS guide notes that it is the latest compatible version of React Native for react-native-macos.

I have the following dependencies installed via npm

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.12",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.8.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native-macos": "^0.64.30",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.10.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.17.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4"
  },
```

When I try to install the react-navigation packages and follow up with the pod-install command we see the following:

```
$ pod --version
1.11.3
$ pod install

Auto-linking React Native modules for target `slidesmacos-iOS`: RNCMaskedView, RNGestureHandler, RNReanimated, RNScreens, and react-native-safe-area-context
Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "react-native-safe-area-context":
  In Podfile:
    react-native-safe-area-context (from `../node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context`)
```

Is react-navigation available for react-native-macos?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you didn't install or the CocoaPods can't find a valid local installation for that lib (`react-native-safe-area-context`).

You can search what libs can be used for each platform at [this website](https://reactnative.directory/?macos=true) (with the flag `?macos=true`) and the `react-navigation` is one of the recommended ones.

About your problem, did you follow up on all the steps from the install guide? It was mentioned about dependencies for [Expo managed](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/#installing-dependencies-into-an-expo-managed-project) and [Bare projects](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/#installing-dependencies-into-an-expo-managed-project). The idea of it is that you need to install 2 more dependencies and one of them is what is missing:

- `react-native-screens`
- `react-native-safe-area-context`

There is also [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66016300/cocoapods-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-pod-firebase-everything/66016902#66016902) where the steps to fix are just some updates. One comment to that answer also stated that it was necessary to run `pod repo update` or `pod install --repo-update`. This could also help you.

Comment: I revised my question to note that all of these dependencies are indeed installed. I have also run the pod repo update command as well.

Comment: If possible, could you please provide some more information about your environment? Such as CocoaPods version, Expo/Bare Metal (and version of it), and the lines from your Podfile. It'll also be nice to know which guide you are following. I found [this one](https://microsoft.github.io/react-native-windows/docs/0.64/rnm-getting-started#install-react-native-for-macos), is this the one you are using?

Comment: Yes, that is the guide I'm following. This is a new from scratch MacOS project, so not using Expo - still learning how to build a MacOS project. I use Expo for my iOS projects. I use the command: npx react-native run-macos

Comment: I added into my question that I have version 1.11.3 for CocoaPod. I've already run the command: pod update

Comment: Also everything works just fine - as expected - until I add in react navigation.